# Do I need to wrap jest tests in try/catch if they include done

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Does a failed test in jest affect other tests that contain done? Can I avoid this without wrapping every test in try and error?

I have tried the following:

I made one test fail.

```
    test('geolocate event', done => {
    ...
            try {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
                done();
            } catch (error) {
                done(error);
            }
        });
```

Result was

```
 FAIL  src/ui/control/geolocate_control.test.ts (14.984 s)
  GeolocateControl with no options
    ✓ with no options (835 ms)
   ...
    ✕ geolocate event (107 ms)
    ✓ trigger (13 ms)
    ✓ trigger before added to map (2 ms)
    ✓ geolocate fitBoundsOptions (31 ms)
    ✓ with removed before Geolocation callback (16 ms)
    ✓ non-zero bearing (19 ms)
...
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 19 passed, 20 total
```

After that I deleted the try and catch

```
    test('geolocate event', done => {
    ...
                expect(true).toBe(false);
                done();
       
    });
```

Result was:

```
 FAIL  src/ui/control/geolocate_control.test.ts (16.636 s)
  GeolocateControl with no options
    ✓ with no options (857 ms)
...
    ✕ geolocate event (38 ms)
    ✓ trigger (15 ms)
    ✓ trigger before added to map (3 ms)
    ✕ geolocate fitBoundsOptions (24 ms)
    ✓ with removed before Geolocation callback (19 ms)
    ✕ non-zero bearing (19 ms)
    ✕ no watching map camera on geolocation (18 ms)
    ✕ watching map updates recenter on location with dot (23 ms)
    ✕ watching map background event (27 ms)
    ✕ watching map background state (16 ms)
    ✓ trackuserlocationstart event (17 ms)
    ✕ does not switch to BACKGROUND and stays in ACTIVE_LOCK state on window resize (22 ms)
    ✕ switches to BACKGROUND state on map manipulation (18 ms)
    ✕ accuracy circle not shown if showAccuracyCircle = false (20 ms)
    ✕ accuracy circle radius matches reported accuracy (20 ms)
    ✕ shown even if trackUserLocation = false (16 ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       12 failed, 8 passed, 20 total
...
```

Therefore, I believe that a test with done, if it fails, will have an impact on other tests.

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Edit:
This is the whole methode:

```
    test('outofmaxbounds event in background state', done => {
        const map = createMap(undefined, undefined);
        const geolocate = new GeolocateControl(undefined);
        map.addControl(geolocate);
        map.setMaxBounds([[0, 0], [10, 10]]);
        geolocate._watchState = 'BACKGROUND';

        const click = new window.Event('click');

        geolocate.on('outofmaxbounds', (position) => {
            try {
                expect(geolocate._watchState).toBe('BACKGROUND_ERROR');
                expect(position.coords.latitude).toBe(10);
                expect(position.coords.longitude).toBe(20);
                expect(position.coords.accuracy).toBe(3);
                expect(position.timestamp).toBe(4);
                done();
            } catch (error) {
                done(error);
            }
        });
        geolocate._geolocateButton.dispatchEvent(click);
        geolocation.send({latitude: 10, longitude: 20, accuracy: 3, timestamp: 4});
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the `...`? Is this even an asynchronous test?

Comment: Thanks. No, only variables are defined there (...). `Expect` only exists in the try/catch block.

Comment: And where does that stray `});` come from?

Comment: Sorry. It came from a wrapped describe. I just corrected it.

Comment: If the test is not asynchronous, you should use neither `try`/`catch` nor `done`.

Comment: I added the whole methode to the question.